# Json path expression for value match

Tags: json, jsonpath

Here, I want to verify if the user's name is john doe or not.

```
{
    "name": "John doe",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "iPhone",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried `$.firstName[?(@.=='John Doe')] and $[?(@.name=='John')]` but nothing is working.

Comment: what language or is this just the input and pure regex? if that is regex `$` denotes end of line and you have it first, if it is jquery you are missing some information, and firstName is not defined in the example

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$[?(@.name == 'John doe')]
```

It will return a non empty array containing the original object if the name matches.

```
$[?(@.name == 'John doe')].name
```

It will return a non empty array containing only the name.

https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

**NOTE: this match may not be supported by all implementations**

Answer (score 0):

You have to point what do you want to use jsonpath or xpath. By the samples in you question I  can guess that you are trying jsonpath.  Since there is no a first name in your json, try this

```
$[?(@ == 'John doe')]  //  result ["John doe"]
```

but i would use just this

```
var ifJohnExist =user.name.includes("John");
```

IMHO nobody is using jsonpath this way, jsonpath is created for a search. So if your json is like this

```
var user=[{
  "name": "John doe",
  "age": 26,
  "address": {
      "streetAddress": "naist street",
      "city": "Nara"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
      {
          "type": "iPhone",
          "number": "0123-4567-8888"
      }
  ]
}];
```

then you can use jsonpath, to find an array element that contains that name

```
$[?(@.name.includes('John'))].name //result ["John doe"]
```

and remember that json path is always returning an array

Comment: My apologies. I did a type in the original post bu putting $[?(@.firstName=='John')]. I have tried $[?(@.name=='John doe')] which doesn't seem to work.  $[?(@ == 'John doe')] does solves the issue, but is it possible to filter it using the property name ? e.g.  $[?(@.name == 'John doe')]

Comment: @Raj It is written in my answer - you are not supposed to use jsonpath for this pourpose, if you can use much more simple syntax

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged the question xpath, the XPath 3.1 solution is

```
?name = "John doe"
```

Earlier versions of XPath do not have JSON support.